# MinGW GCC and G++ Errors in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I'm new to this community and this is my first question. I know many people had had this problem before, but, it seems as if people solved it their own ways and I tried all the solutions I could find in google (and here, respectively), but none of them seem to work for me like it was supposed to. And just to make it clear, I use 32-bit Windows XP. Some versions that may work in 64-bit or newer operating systems may not work on mine.

---

So I'm very new to C and C++, I started by installing the Eclipse CDT, the moment I found out it did not have a compiler was when I installed MinGW which was bundled with a C compiler, a C++ compiler, and the MinGW Developer's Toolkit (which included MinSys). So after that, I started by creating a new empty C++ project called 'HyScript'. And did these:

1. I set the environment variables as:

   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;E:\Mark\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;E:\Mark\MinGW\bin
2. Then, I restarted eclipse, deleted the old projects, and created a new one with the same name (deleted the old folders) and chose the toolchair, "Cross GCC".
3. Now I haven't even started writing code, but there are already 4 errors:
   [Here's the link to the dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uevns2i11nwm4yj/Eclipse.PNG)
4. The last thing I did was open up the CMD before going here, and this happened: [Here's another link to the dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/71tjm6sc3sxpzl0/CMD.png)

I don't understand anymore... What did I do wrong? I set the environment variables right, I supposed. And, after doing some research, I still can't find a proper solution for me. It's been two days now, and this error still hasn't gone away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose wrong toolchair "Cross GCC". Please select "MinGW"

The latest version of G++ can be found [here](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran). Please do NOT install it in the default directory but use this:

> C:\MinGW

If you still have problems, uninstall everything you did, and watch [these video instructions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6x2kh1voR8).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that mistake.